# Trying to embed Lua in c++, "undefined reference to 'dlopen'"

Tags: c++, lua, linker, embedding

**In a nutshell:** compiling and linking c++ program that embeds lua using command `g++ -o clua clua.cpp -Wall -Iinclude -L liblua5.1.a liblua5.1.so -ldl`, getting `liblua5.1.so: undefined reference to 'dlopen'`, among others.

I've been unsuccessfully trying to embed any scripting language in my c++ game for a few weeks now, going from V8 through Python and Squirrel. Lua is marketed as "easy to setup, small", etc, so I figured I'd go with that.

I've gotten the precompiled lua binaries from http://sourceforge.net/projects/luabinaries/files/5.1.5/Linux%20Libraries/ (I used lua-5.1.5_Linux26g4_lib.tar.gz for my **32bit ubuntu 13.something**) and have a simple example program:

```
extern "C" {
#include "lua.h"
#include "lualib.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
}

int main()
{
    lua_State *L = lua_open();

    // load the libs
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    //run a Lua scrip here
    luaL_dofile(L,"foo.lua");

    printf("\nI am done with Lua in C++.\n");

    lua_close(L);

    return 0;
}
```

that is saved as "clua.cpp" and placed in the extracted folder (so that it is in the same directory as "liblua5.1.a" and "liblua5.1.so" and the lua header files are in a folder called "include"). Now, I'm trying to compile the program with the console, using g++, this is the exact command:

```
g++ -o clua clua.cpp -c -Wall -Iinclude
```

And it runs flawlessly, produces no errors, and creates a binary file "clua" as expected. When I try to link however:

```
g++ -o clua clua.cpp -Wall -Iinclude -L liblua5.1.a liblua5.1.so -ldl
```

I get:

```
liblua5.1.so: undefined reference to `dlopen'
liblua5.1.so: undefined reference to `dlclose'
liblua5.1.so: undefined reference to `dlerror'
liblua5.1.so: undefined reference to `dlsym'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have read lots of responses to people having similar questions, options presented are:

- adding "-ldl", no effect there
- making sure "-ldl" is last, did that too
- https://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt/ticket/230 said adding `LDFLAGS="-Wl,--no-as-needed"` or  `--enable-dependency-linking` should do the trick, now, I was not sure exactly how my command was supposed to look, whether to put

  g++ -o clua LDFLAGS="-Wl,--no-as-needed" clua.cpp -Wall -Iinclude -L liblua5.1.a liblua5.1.so -ldl

or

```
g++ -o clua -Wl --no-as-needed clua.cpp -Wall -Iinclude -L liblua5.1.a liblua5.1.so -ldl
```

,

```
g++ --enable-dependency-linking -o clua clua.cpp -Wall -Iinclude -L liblua5.1.a liblua5.1.so -ldl
```

or

```
g++ -o clua clua.cpp -Wall -Iinclude -L liblua5.1.a liblua5.1.so -ldl --enable-dependency-linking
```

but all those gave errors like:

```
cc1plus: error: unknown pass dependency-linking specified in -fenable
```

- https://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt/ticket/229 said: "Another workaround would be to add the configure flag --disable-pthread-mumps", I did that:

  g++ -o clua --disable-pthread-mumps clua.cpp -Wall -Iinclude -L liblua5.1.a liblua5.1.so -ldl

and got

```
cc1plus: error: unknown pass pthread-mumps specified in -fdisable
```

I was running this all from the directory where clua.cpp, liblua5.1.a and liblua5.1.so was, and there was a folder in there named "include" containing headers. I'm running this on 32bit Ubuntu 13.(10, I think).

**Now, what can I do to link Lua properly?**

Comment: [remember](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/), [select isn't broken](http://pragmatictips.com/26), You might want to see, which kinds of lua a aptitude-distributable on your linux and use that, and use a meta-build generator to avoid compile flags errors. See an example [here](https://github.com/d-led/lul)->`premake4.lua`. The problem might be as simple, as that you are just writing wrong flags for gcc

Comment: select isn't broken - nice article, tho I knew most of these things before. Well yes, you're probably right, I'm probably doing something wrong - it's just that I've personally ran out of other things to try. That's why I'm here. I'll go into the example you gave, but if you have the time, could you elaborate on what the problem with my flags might be? As you saw, I tried some things in that area (--enable-dependency-linking, etc.) but perhaps I am putting those in the wrong place in the command?

Comment: It may be simpler just to include the source of Lua into your project and build it with `-DLUA_USE_LINUX`. If you don't need to dynamically load C libraries for Lua, you can disable it in `luaconf.h` and avoid `-ldl`.

Comment: usage of libdl can be disabled? Man, that might solve it all. Will try that first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-L liblua5.1.a liblua5.1.so` looks wrong → [link options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/Link-Options.html) → `-llua5.1`?

Then, there are two different lua libraries on Ubuntu/Debian, as far as I remember, one of which doesn't allow dynamic library loading, hence [`-llua5.1-c++`](https://github.com/d-led/pugilua/blob/master/Build/pugilua.make)  and to get it: `sudo apt-get install lua5.1 liblua5.1-dev`

My advice: simplify, use a meta-make generator if you're struggling with GNU Make

Comment: This looks promising. I will check it as soon as I get home. As a comment tho - I tried -llua5.1 first, and I think it could not find it. But I'm not sure on that, will try again.

Comment: Hah, don't bother, it sure is installed ;). Works from the command line, I can type "lua" and use it interactively.

Comment: Doing `sudo apt-get install lua5.1 liblua5.1-dev` worked! Man, I can't say how thankful I am; I've been unsuccesful in doing this for weeks and it has really stalled my project. And you were right, "select" wasn't broken. So yeah, thank you, really.